# Is 'actiBPM' the best plugin for IntelliJ IDEA when I using 'Activiti'?

Tags: intellij-idea, plugins, activiti

I am using 'Activiti' in my project. 
And a few days ago, I changed my IDE from Eclipse to IntelliJ IDEA. 
'Activiti' has a very useful and friendly plugin for Eclipse which is named as 'Activiti Designer'. 
But I've found that the plugin 'actiBPM' for Intellij when using 'Activiti' is very hard-to-use, and not friendly at all.
So, is there any better plugin I can use for IntelliJ when using 'Activiti'?
Thank you.

Comment: Is there any solution? I tried different plugin but unable to see the diagram. Please share if anyone solved this problem with IntelliJ IDEA 2022.1.3 (Ultimate Edition)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This plug-in appears to be abandoned (didn't update since 2014). I'm afraid, there are no other plug-ins for that at the moment.

You can vote for this request:

- [IDEA-104687](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-104687) Activiti BPM support

Answer (score 1):

There is another alternative today - plugin `Activiti BPMN visualizer`:

https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/15222-activiti-bpmn-visualizer

Features:

- Activiti BPMN dialect diagram visualization and editing
- Code navigation from BPMN to Spring beans
- Code navigation from BPMN diagram to XML
- Code completion for delegate expression and classes
- Refactoring propagation from Java to BPMN thanks to IntelliJ language injection (i.e. class renames will be captured in XML if any class is reference)

Feel free to raise bugs/feature requests at plugin the homepage:

https://github.com/valb3r/flowable-bpmn-intellij-plugin

Disclaimer: I'm the maintainer of this plugin

Answer (score 0):

The built-in "JBoss jBPM" plugin has

- a graphical designer for jpdl (and Activiti *.bpmn20.xml) files with DnD, usages search, rename and inplace editing
- Completion, navigation, refactorings and highlighting inside jpdl xml editor
- Links to processes from class files

For usage details, see [here](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206869349-Generate-BPMN-2-0-diagram). The plugin [apparently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43469842/intellij-idea-plugin-for-bpmn-designer#answer-43471553) requires IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate 2016.3.X or greater.

Another (or additional) option, [mentioned in the IDEA-104687 Activiti BPM support feature request](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-104687#focus=streamItem-27-3140003.0-0), is to use [Camunda Modeler](https://camunda.com/products/modeler/) as an external tool.