# IntelliJ IDEA Plugin for BPMN designer

Tags: intellij-idea, jbpm, bpmn

I've found [this post](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206869349-Generate-BPMN-2-0-diagram) about BPMN files designer, I tried to open designer window in every way, but i can only open diagram preview. Did anyone use jBPM plugin and can tell me how can I open designer window?

## Edit

For simplicity, i'm using this bpmn file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 
<definitions id="definitions"
xmlns="http://www.omg.org/spec/BPMN/20100524/MODEL"
targetNamespace="http://www.activiti.org/bpmn2.0">
 
  <process id="helloWorld">
 
    <startEvent id="start" />
    <sequenceFlow id="flow1" sourceRef="start" targetRef="script" />
    <scriptTask id="script" name="HelloWorld" scriptFormat="groovy">
      <script>
        System.out.println("Hello world")
      </script>
    </scriptTask>
    <sequenceFlow id="flow2" sourceRef="script" targetRef="theEnd" />
    <endEvent id="theEnd" />
 
</process>
 
</definitions>
```

It's from [tutorial](http://www.jorambarrez.be/blog/2010/08/02/tutorial-a-bpmn-2-0-hello-world-with-activiti-5-0-alpha4-in-5-steps/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need any third-party plug-ins, the bundled plug-in works just fine. We've recorded a screencast which shows how to use it:

- [jBPM plugin: how to](http://screencast-o-matic.com/watch/cbfFXsX1gX)

Make sure you have at least 2016.3.x IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate version.

Comment: My problem is i did everything that you've included in screencast (thank you) but still I don't see the designer tab, I only see text xml and i can generate diagram, but can't open designer. See edited post

Comment: v. 2016.1.2 built on April 29, 2016

Comment: You need at least 2016.3 version, the screencast is from 2017 version.

Comment: OK, thank you, unfortunetely my company have this as the latest version :) you can add this explanation to answer for future

Comment: This doesn't work with the latest version of intelliJ. Is there any support or alternate options for this plugin ?

Comment: @Sathiesh please [report a bug](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/newIssue?project=IDEA) with more details.

Comment: I am using 2021.1 , the designer tab is visible after installing the plugin, however when I navigate to the designer tab, a notification pops up: "generating Designer component" and after that Intellij just hangs and doesn't respond. I tried increasing memory etc, nothing is working to my disappointment.